# Vagrantfile::DEFAULT_SERVER_URL `replace': can't modify frozen String

Tags: vagrant

I am a newbie to vagrant. Here is my problem,I download a vagrantfile from a project. But when I run vagrant up in my git bash. it says:

```
 C:/Users/acer/WebstormProjects/fullstack-nanodegree-
 vm/vagrant/Vagrantfile:5:in `replace': can't modify frozen String 
 (RuntimeError)
```

my vagrant version is 2.0.3 and the error place in vagrant file is:

```
 Vagrant::DEFAULT_SERVER_URL.replace('https://vagrantcloud.com')
```

How am I supposed to solve this? I don't have any clues.

Answer (score 4):

Try removing that line from your Vagrantfile. I believe this is related to some fixes that went into 2.0.3 to better handle the vagrantcloud URL changes.

This resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Yes, if your Vagrant version is 2.0.3, then you need not have that line.That line is only required for Vagrant version below 2.0, to cater to vagrant box URL change from older https://atlas.hashicorp.com to newer https://vagrantcloud.com. I had also faced same issue, on upgrading from Vagrant 1.9 to Vagrant 2.1, and my Vagrant file had that line.